# Using cursor to find all employees who need to have their salary updated

Tags: sql, plsql

I have a table called employees.  I am trying to    create an anonymous PLSQL block, which outputs the last names, salary and hiredate of the employees in the employees table. If the employee hiredate is more than 5 years, then next to the employee record I should display the string: ‘Due for a 10% raise’    and calculate that raise and display it next to the record.
I need to use the current year (2016) to do the calcuations to determine that each employee need a raise.

```
set serveroutput on
DECLARE 
  v_empno employees.employee_id%TYPE;
  v_lname employees.last_name%TYPE;
  v_salary employees.salary%TYPE;
  v_hiredate employees.hiredate%TYPE;
  v_newsalary number(8,2); 
  CURSOR c_emp IS 
    SELECT e1.employee_id, e1.last_name, e1.salary, e1.hiredate  
    FROM employees e1, 
        (SELECT employee_id, TRUNC(MONTHS_BETWEEN(sysdate, hiredate)/12) years_of_service 
          FROM employees
        ) e2 
    WHERE e1.employee_id =e2.employee_id and years_of_service >5; 
  BEGIN

    OPEN c_emp; 
    LOOP
      FETCH c_emp  into v_empo, v_lname, v_salary, v_hiredate
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( v_empno ||'  '||v_lname || ' ' || v_salary ||'  '||v_hiredate );  
    END LOOP; 
  END;
```

[image: Table]

Comment: So what is the problem? Did you get any errors?

Comment: I did get a few errors but it was telling me that I was using the cursor incorrectly and didnt compile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You program is anyways wrong. I dont think it would had ever complied. Please check below the working version:

```
DECLARE 
  v_empno emp.empno%TYPE;
  v_lname emp.ename%TYPE;
  v_salary emp.sal%TYPE;
  v_hiredate emp.hiredate%TYPE;
  v_newsalary number(8,2); 
  CURSOR c_emp IS 
    SELECT e1.empno, e1.ename, e1.sal, e1.hiredate 
    FROM emp e1, 
        (SELECT empno, TRUNC(MONTHS_BETWEEN(sysdate, hiredate)/12) years_of_service 
          FROM emp
        ) e2 
    WHERE e1.empno =e2.empno 
    and years_of_service >5; 
BEGIN
    OPEN c_emp; 
    LOOP
      FETCH c_emp  
      into v_empno, v_lname, v_salary, v_hiredate;

      v_newsalary := v_salary + (v_salary*.1);

      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( v_empno ||'  '||v_lname || ' ' || v_salary ||'  '||v_hiredate||'    '||'Due for a 10% raise'||'  '||v_newsalary);
      exit when c_emp%NOTFOUND;  
    END LOOP; 
    close c_emp;
  END;
```

Comment: Thanks for the correction. I forgot to close the cursor after searching for every row!

Answer (score 0):

Rather than doing your entire homework assignment for you, I'll just suggest that you don't need the `declare` section at all as you can simply define the cursor inline with

```
for r in (
    select e.blah from employees e
)
loop
    do stuff here referring to r.blah
end loop;
```

(I always use `r` for cursor loops and `i` for numeric loops, unless there is some complicating factor.)

Also you don't need a self join to check whether `hiredate < add_months(sysdate,-60)` as you can just use a `case` expression.

Since you are just starting, I'd also advise you to choose the path of lowercase, because it's 2016 not 1974.

Comment: I have always seen code written for SQL in caps. It makes it a lot easier. I think it is a stylistic choice when people write SQL. How would a case expression work for this implementation? I am really interested knowing how to implemented so next time if i encounter it I would know how it would work.

Comment: I have also seen a lot of SQL written a lot of ways. I used to tell myself capitalising keywords made it easier to read, until I realised it actually didn't. Regarding your hiredate expression, just have 'case when blah < whatever then 'Y' end' in your select list, no join needed.

Comment: So that would go in the first where clause or in the from clause? I think it would make a lot of sense if I put it in the where clause.

Comment: Looks like your requirement is to list all employees, and only append the comment when hiredate is more than 5 years ago. If so, you don't want to filter the rows, and it would just go in the select list. Then you could use that value in the loop to decide whether to print the 'due raise' text.