# Comparing dates to today's date

Tags: plsql, cursor

I am trying to write a PL/SQL query with a cursor that will retrieve all the employees hiring date and flag the ones who have been there for more than 5 years by having their raise calculated (let's say 10%) and have "raise" right next to their names.

I put this query together but I am having a hard time correcting the errors that I get.

```
declare
    cursor c_emp_raise is
        select last_name, salary, hire_date 
        from employees
        where hire_date+1825 < trunc(sysdate);
    v_l_name employees.last_name%type;
    v_sal employees.salary%type;
    v_h_date emplyees.hire_date%TYPE;
begin
    open c_emp_raise;
    loop
      fetch c_emp_raise into v_l_name, v_sal, v_h_date;
      exit when c_emp_raise%NOTFOUND;
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_l_name ||' '||v_sal||' '||v_h_date
             ||' Due for 10% Raise '||v_sal*0.1);
    END LOOP;
END;
```

The error that I get refers to a line that I do not have line 13 column 52, and I also get other errors that are not specific.
Any help will be welcome.

Thank you

Comment: Have a look at [other posts on the same homework assignment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38409748/using-cursor-to-find-all-employees-who-need-to-have-their-salary-updated/38410292#38410292).

Answer (score 1):

You misspelled employees:

```
v_h_date   emplyees.hire_date%TYPE;
```

When you ask a question show the error stack:

```
ORA-06550: Zeile 7, Spalte 10:
PLS-00201: Bezeichner 'EMPLYEES.HIRE_DATE' muss deklariert werden
ORA-06550: Zeile 7, Spalte 10:
PL/SQL: Item ignored
ORA-06550: Zeile 11, Spalte 43:
PLS-00320: Die Typ-Deklaration dieses Ausdruckes ist unvollständig oder fehlerhaft
ORA-06550: Zeile 11, Spalte 3:
PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
ORA-06550: Zeile 13, Spalte 52:
PLS-00320: Die Typ-Deklaration dieses Ausdruckes ist unvollständig oder fehlerhaft
ORA-06550: Zeile 13, Spalte 3:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
```

And then correct the errors one by one. The first one is on line 7 column 10